# Reordering column index of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, columnsorting

I have a data frame of 15k columns. These columns are to be re-ordered. Such that. These columns are arranged as follows:

1) The first column should have values of third
2)  The second column should have values of first
3) The third column should have values of first

**Existing Column**

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 .....14998 14999 15000

**Desired Columns**

2 0 1 5 3 4 8 6 7 .... 15000 14998 14999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, even simpler solution:

```
import itertools

k = [2, -1, -1] * (len(x)//3)
indexes = np.arange(15000) + np.array(k)

df.iloc[:, indexes]
```

Comment: Works well now:)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is regex!

```
teststring=" ".join(str(i) for i in range(0,15000))
replacedstring=re.sub(r'((\d+) (\d+) (\d+))',r'\4 \2 \3',teststring)
replacedstring.split(" ")
```